# How to override default upload path of sonata media bundle in symfony?

Tags: php, symfony, sonata-media-bundle

I have the following problem, I'm working in a Symfony 2 application using Sonata Media bundle for media upload, I'm hosting the app in Bluehost, and my question is, how can I override the default path of media upload in sonata media bundle?, because I need to upload to "public_html" directory instead of the default web directory?, thanks and kind regards/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [possible configuration](https://sonata-project.org/bundles/media/master/doc/reference/advanced_configuration.html) of Sonata Media Bundle.

As you can see, you can provide a destination path for your media files via filesystem configuration.

Default value is:

```
%kernel.root_dir%/../web/uploads/media
```

Custom path (media folder is on the same level as project folder):

```
sonata_media:
    filesystem:
        local:
            directory:  %kernel.root_dir%/../../media
            create:     false
```

*create*: *true* means that a specified directory will be created if it does not exist.